# how to get data from DB on change of dropdown in ASP.NET and show it as a link for downloading file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need a page which should show a drop down, which contains data from DB. on select of a particular item from DB it should send some parameter and get a set of result which should show as a link.

on click of that link, it should send a parameter to action result export and download a file.

I a have created action method to download a file.
but how to do getting data on select of dropdown and result showing as links?

```
 public ActionResult Export(int? protocol)
 {
     if(procol!=null)
     {
         // create file
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvData))
         {
             return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvData), "text/csv", "report.csv");
         }
      }
      return view()
  }
```

this is what i have in my controller to create and download file

Comment: Use Jquery .onChange() Event and in that change function write a some code to fetch Particular data based upon the selection and then call ur Export method

Comment: can i use angular js to do onchange function and create api to get data. and creating links?
but links should hit controller

Comment: Yes you can use AngularJS to achieve the same and create API(only if u think its necessary) and hit the Export controllers to download a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Ajax to achieve this.

C# snippet:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
return Json(//method to get data, JsonsResultBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

Jquery Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("", "")',
            data: { id: element.prop("id") },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
```